# Ctrl + c in DataGridViewCell edit mode copies the whole row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridviewtextboxcell

I have a datagrid that has one column with text that I would like to allow users to copy text out of.  I have set up routines to be able to copy the entire cell, or row, but I am having issues when editing the cell and typing CTRL + C.

This is the code I am using to allow the cell to be edited.  Once inside, I can highlight text and right click it for copy.  This works just fine, it is if I highlight text and type CTRL + C that it then copies the row, instead of the highlighted text.

I don't want to have to create my own class, and if it isn't possible I will just leave it as it is.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.EditingControl == null ||
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditType != typeof (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl))
    return;
    dataGridView1.CancelEdit();
    dataGridView1.EndEdit();
}

private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.EditType == typeof(DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl))
    {
    dataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you handling `KeyUp` or `KeyDown` somewhere?  My guess is you have overridden this key combination to copy full rows and now need to handle single rows when the row is in edit mode.

Comment: I am not handling those keys, just the clicks on some ToolStripMenuItems.  I put in some breakpoints in all of the places that I am doing any kind of copy and they are never tripped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are having the `SelectionMode` property as `FullRowSelect` then it will copy the entire row even if a cell is in edit mode. Change the value to `CellSelect`. Set the below properties to copy only the editing cell content using CTRL + C.

```
dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;
dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
```

Comment: Yay!  Now I can, so I just did.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 11):

I was having the exact same problem as the OP and needed a solution with one slight difference.  I needed DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect not CellSelect.  I was able to achieve this by doing the following:

```
datagridview1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
datagridview1.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.Disable;
datagridview1.MultiSelect = false;
```

I believe setting ClipboardCopyMode disable defeats the built-in grid function and what's left is standard MS Windows behavior.  So I am able to select text in an editable cell and enter ctrl-C to copy "just" the selected text.
-OR-  It's quite possible there has been a behavior change between .NET versions since this was first posted.  In any case this works for me using Visual Studio 2013, .NET 4.5 and windows 7.

Also important to note:  I my case I only cared about being able to copy/paste editable columns/cells.  This solution achieves this.  Right click still works too.

Other grid settings that might be important to viewers:

```
datagridview1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
datagridview1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
datagridview1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!